# Настройка Apache Cassandra

Tags: nosql

Недавно начал работать с Cassandra. Хотелось бы узнать из опыта бывалых людей, как влияют на скорость записи в базу следующие параметры, настраиваемые в cassandra.yaml:

```
memtable_flush_writers
memtable_flush_queue_size
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb
slised_buffer_size_in_kb
thrift_max_message_length_in_mb
binary_memtable_throughput_in_mb
column_index_size_in_kb
```

Интересует личный опыт людей, которые сталкивались с Cassandra (что и как изменяли и к чему это приводило).

Comment: не уверен, что туда, там про это видимо ничего не знают, ну или делают вид, что не знают((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел еще очень полезную инфу по этой теме [Apache Cassandra 1.0 Documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/index).